# How to find the list of changes from a specific branch from specific date to specific date in github

Tags: github

I would like to find out the list of changes/files from a specific branch from specific date to specific date in github using command or any way.So that I will check the commits/changes what ever is done and find out the impacts to my application which is having issues in the production.Kindly help me on this.
I tried to clone specific branch code and trying to check git log commands but nothing seems to be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just switch branch you want to check commits. `git checkout branchName`

And then type `git log —since=‘Feb 1 2022’ —until=‘Feb 28 2022’`